# Reverting differencing for Time Series VAR model component wise?

Tags: data-transformation, vector-autoregression, differencing

I have data with seasonality so I used seasonal and then first order differencing to make the series stationary in order to fit VAR model.

After the model is fitted on the differenced level I can revert in the usual way using the cumulative sum and the original series. However, I would like also to have the 'components' of the model in the original scale. That is to say, I would like to decompose the fitted result into a constant term and summands from each series on original non-differenced level. Is this possible?

Comment: The fitted values are just linear combinations of the variables, are they not? So if you are able to obtain the variables, obtaining a linear combination should not be too hard.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for helping. Can it be true that the parameters I have found that make a linear combination to the fitted value on the differenced level are the same parameters I can use to get a linear combination on the non-differenced level? This seems intuitively unlikely to me because the parameters interact with the lags multiplicatively but differencing is an additive transformation.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Let me post an answer with what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case of a univariate AR(1). If
$$
\Delta x_t=\varphi_1 \Delta x_{t-1}+u_t
$$
then
$$
x_t=(1+\varphi_1) x_{t-1}-\varphi_1 x_{t-2}+u_t
$$
and
$$
\hat x_t=(1+\hat\varphi_1) x_{t-1}-\hat\varphi_1 x_{t-2}.
$$
If you are able to obtain $x_{t-1}$ and $x_{t-2}$ and you have the estimated coefficient $\hat\varphi_1$, then you can obtain $\hat x_t$.

The case of a multivariate VAR(p) uses the same logic.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yes I can generalise this to VAR(p).

Comment: @Lukas, you are welcome!